# MSBuild, Can I take UsingTask output and use it in a Copy task?

Tags: c#, msbuild

Given: 
MSBuild that comes with Visual Studio 2019
I'm trying to take output from code task and use it in a CopyTask.

MSBuild Inline Task Reference [Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019)

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- This simple inline task displays "Hello, world!" -->
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="HelloWorld"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup />
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
<![CDATA[
// Display "Hello, world!"
Log.LogError("Hello, world!");
]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

Somehow take code output and place it in a property so I can use it in a CopyTask?

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <HelloWorld /> 
    <Copy SourceFiles="" DestinationFiles="<HelloWorld />"
  </Target>
```

Comment: Normally, MSBuild tasks expose properties that are used as output parameters, which you can then pass to other tasks. This is separate from the logging. Just so I understand your question, you're wanting to get the text "Hello, world!" to appear in a file somewhere?

Comment: Yes, somehow use that string in DestinationFiles attribute of Copy task. Basically, I'm trying to specify a dynamic folder name in the destination

Comment: Read up on [input and output parameters to tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019#input-and-output-parameters). You will need to assign the string "Hello, world!" to an output parameter inside your task, then when you call your task you will need to consume the value in an MSBuild property, before finally using the [`WriteLinesToFile` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writelinestofile-task?view=vs-2019) (instead of `Copy`, which copies an existing file on the filesystem).

Comment: How do I assign an output parameter  from code element?

Answer (score 3):

Credit to @Joe Sewell for comments in OP.

Found answer:

Article link [Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-inline-task?view=vs-2019#define-the-adder-task)

```
<UsingTask TaskName="Adder" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <A ParameterType="System.Int32" Required="true" />
    <B ParameterType="System.Int32" Required="true" />
    <C ParameterType="System.Int32" Output="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      C = A + B;
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
<Target Name="TestBuild">
  <Adder A="4" B="5">
    <Output PropertyName="Sum" TaskParameter="C" />
  </Adder>
  <Message Text="The sum is $(Sum)" Importance="High" />
</Target>
```